# Why does terraform plan lock the state?

Tags: terraform

**Q: What's the point for the `terraform plan` operation to lock the state by default?**

(I know it might be disabled with [`-lock=false`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/plan.html#lock-true))

Context:

- (As far as I understand) The `plan` operation is not supposed to alter state.
- `plan` does start with some version of `refresh` (which typically alters state), but even the standard output of `terraform plan` pro-actively says it's not the case with the plan-initiated refresh:

```
    Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...
    The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be
    persisted to local or remote state storage.
```

- I saw [this question](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/why-does-a-plan-lock-the-state-file/3520) on the Hashicorp website, which doesn't seem to provide a conclusive answer.

Comment: One idea that comes to my mind is - that locking might be used to ensure structural consistency of the state. I.e. Terraform might not guarantee that the state during other running `apply` (holding a lock) is consistent the whole time.
But that's only a guess.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is because behind the scenes it performs a state refresh:

> -refresh=false - Disables the default behavior of synchronizing the Terraform state with remote objects before checking for configuration changes.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/plan.html

The other reason I can think of is that if you run a plan and someone already locked the state, it means it is performing changes to the state so reading the state might give you a plan that is no longer valid after the lock is freed

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/28130